# Printing HTML document from a fragment in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, printing

I'm attempting to make an Android app that adds data to an HTML document on one fragment and prints out that document with the click of a button on another fragment. I'm trying to use [this](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs) page on the Android Documentation as a guide, but the button doesn't do anything when clicked. I didn't see anything in the logcat when testing on an emulator, but when testing on a real device I see the following error:

`E/DatabaseIndexingManager: Cannot find SearchIndexableResources for class name: com.android.settings.print.PrintSettingsFragment`

UPDATE: Even though I haven't changed anything yet, the app now crashes as soon as the fragment is selected. The logcat now gives the following error:

`E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.google.android.ims
    PID: 3635
    Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.telephony.action.CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED flg=0x15000010 cmp=com.google.android.ims/.receivers.CarrierConfigChangedReceiver (has extras) }`

It then proceeds to give a bunch of stats about  CPU usage.

Code for fragment:

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button button = container.findViewById(R.id.button);

        //declaring OnClickListener as an object
        View.OnClickListener btnClick = (View v) ->  doWebViewPrint();

        button.setOnClickListener(btnClick);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.placeholder2, container, false);
    }

    private void doWebViewPrint() {
        // Create a WebView object specifically for printing
        WebView webView = new WebView(getActivity());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "page finished loading " + url);
                createWebPrintJob(view);
                mWebView = null;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/calendar.html");
        mWebView = webView;
    }
    private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

        // Get a PrintManager instance
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

        // Get a print adapter instance
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName);

        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
                new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());

    }
}
```

Placeholder2.xml (I'll change the names later):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wv">
    </WebView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_print"
        android:paddingStart="50dp"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to set the OnClickListener before inflating it. I moved these lines:

```java
Button button = container.findViewById(R.id.button);

        //declaring OnClickListener as an object
        View.OnClickListener btnClick = (View v) ->  doWebViewPrint();

        button.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
```

to an onViewCreated function. Credit to Redditor [redditbricks](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/duquw4/weekly_questions_thread_november_11_2019/f7ldmfm?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) for noticing my mistake.